# Elements with widths that sum to 100% tend to over/underflow

Tags: css, width

I want to display a timeline for my workouts, but all of the widths combined (even though they equal 100%) overflow. How can I get them to always fit 100% of the width perfectly?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lzqvk/

HTML:

```
<div class="workoutTimeline">
 <div class="section vertical yellow" style="width:7.117437722419928%">
  <div class="exercise" style="width:33.33333333333333%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:33.33333333333333%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:33.33333333333333%"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="section vertical orange" style="width:35.58718861209964%">
  <div class="exercise" style="width:50%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:50%"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="section vertical red" style="width:32.02846975088968%">
  <div class="exercise" style="width:5.555555555555555%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:5.555555555555555%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:5.555555555555555%"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="section vertical blue" style="width:21.352313167259783%">
  <div class="exercise" style="width:100%"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="section vertical purple" style="width:7.117437722419928%">
  <div class="exercise" style="width:25%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:25%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:25%"></div>
  <div class="exercise" style="width:25%"></div>
 </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.workoutTimeline {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;

    .section {
        float: left;
        opacity: 0.5;
        height: 100%;

        &.active {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .exercise {
            float: left;
            opacity: 0.5;
            height: 100%;

            &.active {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `7.117437722419928 + 35.58718861209964 + 32.02846975088968 + 21.352313167259783 + 7.117437722419928 = 103.20284697508895` did I miss something? (Chrome 23.0.1271.64) EDIT: see this cleaned up fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Uq7c/

Comment: Consider UL/LI elements instead of DIV\DIV.

Comment: That was the right answer - thanks. I am seeing this with widths of 1/7 in my iOS mobile website, though. I'll post a similar question. Thanks!
@ŠimeVidas Why do you say that?

Comment: @Garrett Because your ".section" elements are lists of ".exercise" elements.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was for a reason other than semantics. Thanks.